# Запрещение кастинга виртуального базового класса

Tags: c++

Почему запрещён кастинг в следующем коде?

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived : virtual public Base
{
};

int main()
{
    Base *p = new Derived;
    static_cast<Derived *>(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Компилятор не может скастовать `Base*` к `Derived*`, потому что он не делает полный анализ кода, а значит не знает как именно расположены типы друг относительно друга.

Если существуют только типы `Base` и `Derived`, то при касте `Base*` в `Derived*` надо добавить смещение в 0 байт, т.к. адреса `Derived` и `Base` совпадают.
Однако компилятор допускает, что может существовать другие типы, например

```
struct Derived2 : virtual Base { char x[1024]; };
struct MostDerived : virtual Derived2, Derived {};
```

И `Base* p` может указывать на объект этого типа. Тогда `MostDerived` выглядит в памяти так:

```
смещение  | что находится
0         | MostDerived
0         | Base
0         | Derived2 
0         | char Derived2::x[1024]
1024      | Derived
```

Виртуальный базовый класс `Base`, находится в `Derived2`, самом первом базовом классе `MostDerived`. Т.к. `Base` - это пустой базовый класс, он не занимает никакого места в памяти. После `Derived2` будет располагаться `Derived`, уже без `Base`. По этому в этом случае при касте `Base*` в `Derived*` надо добавить смещение в 1024 байт.

Т.к. компилятор не знает какое именно смещение надо использовать, он не может сделать такой `static_cast`.

По этому для виртуальных базовых типов поддерживается только `dynamic_cast`, и то, только для типов в которых есть виртуальные функции.

Comment: При использовании dynamic_cast - C2683 dynamic_cast: "Base" не является полиморфным типом. И на msdn предлагают решение использовать static_cast

Comment: @Abyx: Реально круто. Но вы бы всё же расписали немного в деталях, почему именно так, и какой memory layout в этом случае. (Потому что я тупил несколько минут.)

Comment: А каст указателя работает всегда...

Comment: Упс.. Я имел в виду `(Derived*)p;`, но я не прав - оно тоже [не компилируется](http://codepad.org/DmoD3HNU).

Comment: @Abyx - ваша табличка является достаточно опасным примером. Кто-то может решить, что компилятор так и работает.

Нужно понимать, что непосредственная реализация классов - личное дело компилятора и оптимизатора. Он может с удовольствием вышвырнуть виртуальные методы и заменить их на реальные, если обнаружит такую возможность. И ваша картинка уже будет враньем, к сожалению.

И как это у вас Base не занимает никакого мета в памяти? sizeof(Base)==1, если что. http://ideone.com/6wU2bu

Comment: @gbg: Даже если `sizeof(Base)` больше нуля, внутри `Derived` он имеет право иметь размер 0, если я правильно помню.

Comment: Вот, кстати, хорошее описание по этому поводу: http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html

Comment: @VlaD - я бы не стал выдумывать объяснений того, как компилятор C++ генерирует классы - это его личное дело. Все статьи, не являющиеся исходниками конкретных версий компилятора - это домыслы и городские легенды. Он может вообще все это вышвырнуть на деле и по регистрам разложить - как вы это объясните?

Comment: @gbg: Вы правы в том, что у каждого компилятора имеет право быть организовано по-своему, бинарного стандарта нету. Насколько я понимаю, здесь описывается распространённая модель (gcc?). Но каким компиляторам соответствует эта модель, вопрос к автору ответа.

Comment: @Abyx: Спасибо!